# postgresql-why row share lock conflicts with row exclusive lock?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking

[Postgresql official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) states: ROW EXCL is not conflicting with ROW SHARE. But

If execute the statement `select * from demo for update` in one transaction and execute the statement `update demo set ...` in another transaction, then the second transaction will await the first commit.

My understanding is: the first transaction only acquire ROW SHARE lock on every row, and the second just acquire ROW EXCLUSIVE lock, they should not conflict with each other, at least as official doc said.

And if I lock whole table as ROW SHARE lock, then there will be no the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at table level locks

> Remember that all of these lock modes are table-level locks, even if the name contains the word “row”; the names of the lock modes are historical.

For UPDATE/SELECT, the next chapter about [**row level** locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) is the important part to look at

> Row-Level Lock Modes
>
> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, **other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE, SELECT FOR SHARE or SELECT FOR KEY SHARE of these rows will be blocked** until the current transaction ends.

(emphasis mine)